# How to add different auth for different environments in amplify project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Is it possible to add different auth (cognito) inside one amplify project, but for different environments?

Currently I have amplify project with adjusted cognito authentication and it work fine.
I want to add another environment where I have to use different user pool.

I ran following commands inside amplify project:

```
$ amplify init
Do you want to use an existing environment? No
Enter a name for the environment new_env
```

And after this new environment was created. But when I try to add auth it says:

```
$ amplify add auth
Auth has already been added to this project. To update run amplify update auth.
```

And looks like `amplify update auth` tries to update existing auth and not add a new one

Answer (score 2):

Amplify allows you to create multiple environments and add independent features on each one, and is easy to manage like git branches workflow.

To add a new env run `amplify env checkout ENV_NAME`. This will create a new env, like a branch on git, and allow you to add the resources that you need. After that, run `amplify push` to create the resources on cloud.

To list available/created env run `amplify env list`

To switch to an env run `amplify env checkout ENV_NAME`, the same as to create.

Ref: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/overview/

Comment: At first, I was tripped up by this since I thought all the Cognito user pool information was stored in aws-exports.js. I didn't think it was working but when I ran it, to my surprise a different pool had been created behind the scenes. When you change your amplify environment ie `amplify env checkout <env>` it automatically updates the projects aws-exports.js file. Pretty slick!